# Michael Hartl's Railstutorial : Listing 7.32: A template for tests of the error messages

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

The example code:

```
assert_select 'div#<CSS id for error explanation>'
assert_select 'div.<CSS class for field with error>'
```

This generates:
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.                                           ] 16% Time: 00:00:01,  ETA: 00:00:06
unexpected '#' after '[#]' (called from block in  at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:25)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion was not run because of an invalid css selector.
unexpected '<' after '.' (called from block in  at /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:26)

I read somewhere that versions 4.2+ need an other way to do assert_select. Is that true? And what should be used?
[ I have to say; I am still an absolute beginner ]

Answer (score 0):

substitute a `your-class` under `<CSS class...>`, and `your-id` under `<CSS id ...>`

Comment: assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'